# Xcode 5 - App passes validation, icon grayed out after installing via iTunes

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes, adhoc

Doing my final testing before submitting to the app store, I'm able to archive and validate my app, then when I double-click my IPA and iTunes asks me if I want to replace the app in the iTunes Library, I click yes, sync the device.

1. The app icon doesn't show up.
2. The app stays "grayed" out.
3. If I tap on the grayed out app icon, the name changes to "installing..." even though the sync has finished, and at this point nothing happens.

A few weeks ago I was able to complete this process with no problems with the exact same provisioning profile, exact same device.

The problem only started the second time around, when I had to "replace" the IPA in the iTunes Library.

I just took a look at my device in organizer, and there are NO device log, at all.

Answer (score 5):

Turns out the app was being signed with the wrong profile. I created a new ad-hoc profile, and signed the app with that. Seems to be working fine.

EDIT: More specifically, when I was archiving the app, it was being signed with a distribution profile, but when I was "distributing" it from the Organizer, I was signing it with an Ad-Hoc profile. Once I signed both the archive and the export, with the same ad-hoc profile, the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I went to my **updates tab** located in the "App Store" icon. Select the app that is stuck installing.  It brings you to the app details, reviews, etc. Then click on the app icon located at the top left of the screen. When you do this it places the app onto your home screen.  Click on the app again that has been placed on the home screen and it should start installing.